# Unable to open file resource compress.zlib

Tags: php, nginx, typo3, hhvm, typo3-6.2.x

Fresh new installed HHVM nginx enviroment running typo3 6.2.5, getting the following error in the extension manager:

```
Unable to open file resource compress.zlib:///var/www/hhvm/typo3temp/1.mirrors.xml.gz.
```

HHVM --version:

```
HipHop VM 3.3.0 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.3.0-0-g0a3cfb87b8a353fc7e1d15374f4adc413e37aba9
Repo schema: 9a391d9a03e15fccba1cde6d35c05b7cdd380238
Extension API: 20140829
```

HHVM error log entry:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Exception\\ExtensionManagerException'
with message 'Unable to open file resource compress.zlib:///var/www/hhvm/typo3temp/1.mirrors.xml.gz.'
in /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Utility/Parser/MirrorXmlPullParser.php:59
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Utility/Importer/MirrorListUtility.php(70): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Utility\\Parser\\MirrorXmlPullParser->parseXml()
#1 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Utility/Repository/Helper.php(226): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Utility\\Importer\\MirrorListUtility->getMirrors()
#2 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Utility/Repository/Helper.php(165): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Utility\\Repository\\Helper->getMirrors()
#3 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Utility/Repository/Helper.php(106): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Utility\\Repository\\Helper->getRemoteExtListFile()
#4 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extensionmanager/Classes/Controller/ListController.php(124): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Utility\\Repository\\Helper->fetchExtListFile()
#5 (): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extensionmanager\\Controller\\ListController->distributionsAction()
#6 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/ActionController.php(286): call_user_func_array()
#7 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/ActionController.php(157): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\ActionController->callActionMethod()
#8 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Dispatcher.php(69): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\ActionController->processRequest()
#9 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Web/BackendRequestHandler.php(33): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#10 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php(195): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\BackendRequestHandler->handleRequest()
#11 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php(184): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->handleRequest()
#12 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Core/ModuleRunner.php(67): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->run()
#13 /var/www/hhvm/typo3/mod.php(38): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\ModuleRunner->callModule()
#14 {main}
```

Comment: Fix is coming soon https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/842d6fb7dcd6d669b41bf179ec4602793fa38a7a

Answer (score 0):

Please add `hhvm.libxml.ext_entity_whitelist =`file,compress.zlib` to you ini file.

If this does not work, try to get a newer version of `HHVM`.

Comment: Which one? php.ini or server.ini

Comment: This is hhvm specific, therefore `server.ini` I think. Please consult the manual for detailed information. I currently do not use hhvm and cannot assist you with detailed information.

Comment: What version of HHVM do you use? If compiled yourself, did you add the zlib flag?